# Subscript notation in partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

just want to be clear with partial derivative notation, and as to what respect we are taking the partial deriv of , for example; $$f_x, f_y, f_{xx}, f_{yy}, f_{xy}$$

so with what respect is each partial deriv being taken of? are they all with respect to x?

Answer (score 3):

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $f \in C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Then
$$f_x(x_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0)$$
$$f_y(x_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0)$$
$$(f_x)_x(x_0,y_0) = f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) =\frac{\partial \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big)}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\left.\partial x\right.^2}(x_0, y_0)$$
$$(f_x)_y(x_0,y_0) = f_{xy}(x_0,y_0) =\frac{\partial \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big)}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(x_0, y_0)$$

Is it clear now? I hope so!

Comment: Errr... not quite so clear.  The Legendre notation _does_ work as you've written it, in which successive derivatives are added on to the subscripts from left to right.  _Unfortunatately_, the other notation descends, I think, from Liebniz: the first two terms in your equation for the "mixed" partial derivative are correct, but successive derivatives thus get added on _from the left_.  Thus  $\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})}{\partial y}  = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} $ .  (I used to get confused by this, too...)

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was another abandoned thread, since the OP evidently is inactive.  But the last equation did need to be remarked upon.  Thanks for fixing it!